# How do I display a specific number of questions from this JavaScript output?

Tags: javascript

In the following script, how do I go about displaying a specific number of the  5 questions. For example, I only want to display 3 of the questions.

Here's the fully functioning **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/WgRevG)** for reference.

Is there a quick fix for that?

```
var $progressValue = 0;
var resultList=[];


const quizdata=[
      {
        question:"Characterized by skill at understanding and profiting by circumstances",
        options:["Prescient", "Analyst", "Diminution", "Shrewd"],
        answer:"Shrewd"
      },
      {
        question:"To refuse to acknowledge as one's own or as connected with oneself",
        options:["Prevalent", "Disown", "Squalid", "Employee"],
        answer:"Disown"
      },
      {
        question:"Not having the abilities desired or necessary for any purpose",
        options:["Incompetent", "Impoverish", "Coxswain", "Devious"],
        answer:"Incompetent"
      },
      {
        question:"Lizard that changes color in different situations",
        options:["Scruple", "Depredation", "Chameleon", "Whimsical"],
        answer:"Chameleon"
      },
      {
        question:"Having the title of an office without the obligations",
        options:["Reciprocal", "Unsullied", "Titular", "Inflated"],
        answer:"Titular"
      }
    ];
```

Comment: use `.slice()` function

Comment: Three questions? Three random questions? What have you tried? What went wrong, and in what way? Is this all the (relevant) code you have?

Comment: you know which 3 you want, or you want to show it in a random way?

Comment: @CalvinNunes - the goal was to just display a count of 3. It's already set to randomize the output.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Please see the codepen. It's linked. That's all the relevant code. I simply don't know what function applies here.

Comment: Then it's in the wrong place, and you shouldn't expect anyone to go see it. Your [mcve] code should be *in* the question, not just linked from the question. A live demo is a bonus, but it's not a replacement.

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas. I've learned and I will not let it happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the generateQuestions function like so:

```
/*** Return shuffled question ***/
function generateQuestions(qtty = -1){
  var questions=shuffleArray(quizdata);    
  if (qtty > 0) questions = questions.slice(0, qtty);
  return questions;
}
```

this will make it receive an optional parameter telling it to return a specific number of questions.

You will have to change it's call (it's on $(document).ready() near line 297) to pass the desired number of questions.

One thing you could do to make it clear is to include the number of questions on a hidden input. like that:

```
<input type="hidden" id="QttyQuestions" value="3" />
```

And then, look for the `generateQuestions()` call (you can search for "`questions=generateQuestions();`" on your code) and change it like so:

```
questions=generateQuestions($('#QttyQuestions').val());
```

Comment: I did what you suggested. Here's the updated [Pen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/WgRevG)... But it's still displaying all the questions.

Comment: Did you changed the call for that function as well? In your new Pen it's on line 255: `var questions=generateQuestions(2);` (like that it will run with only 2 questions);

Comment: just appended some direct instructions on my answer on how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help!